# ReadKey does not wait for input when executed in PowerShell remote session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

In my scripts when some user interaction must have done, I wait for user to allow continue with: (and it works fine)

```
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

However if the very same script runs in a remote session via Invoke-Command

```
Invoke-Command -Session $remoteSession -ScriptBlock {
    & "./myscript.ps1" # <-- This is the script where the ReadKey executed
}
```

myscript.ps1 is on the remote machine. All of its output correctly displayed in the local machine PowerShell window. But when the ReadKey executed it does not wait, runs to the next statement.

**Question**

Is it by design, or am I missing something? How can I wait in this case?

Comment: As far as I know you can't execute readkeys remote.

Comment: this is a surprising limitation, redirecting standard in and out, and only the out is working correctly

Comment: It has to do with the fact that you've got limited access to the "user space" (you also can't trigger a Winforms dialog remotely for instance)

Comment: You could use `Read-host` instead.

Comment: Your script is being run non-interactively in the background on a remote system. Who or what is supposed to be pressing a key there in the first place?